# Get short windows language name

Tags: delphi

i get the list of installed language on windows with below code :

```
var 
  AList : array [0..9] of LongWord; 
  AklName: array [0..255] of Char; 
  i: Longint; 
begin 
  for i:= 0 to GetKeyboardLayoutList(SizeOf(AList), AList)- 1 do 
  begin 
    GetLocaleInfo(LoWord(AList[i]), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, AklName, SizeOf(AklName)); 
    Memo1.Lines.AddObject(AklName, Pointer(AList[i])); 
  end; 
end;
```

it works correctly but i want get installed language in short names like ( English -> EN ; German -> de ; Persian -> FA) , any one can help me to change this code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `LOCALE_SLANGUAGE`, use one of [the `LOCALE_SISO*` constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373848.aspx), probably `LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME`.

Comment: so LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME would return EN, what would be the one for getting 'EN-US'?

Comment: Good question, @Warren. I don't know anything about this stuff. I could only answer this question because I read the documentation for GetLocaleInfo and followed all the links. Try asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

..or use LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, but it will be display as 'ENG', 'RUS' etc.